# Esper is not defrencing objects and leading to oom for aggregated objects

Tags: events, out-of-memory, dereference, esper

We are Esper To aggregate i.e group by on certain set of events...but esper is not dereferencing that aggregate object.

Esper query:

```
  private static final String HOURLY_CONTEXT =
  "create context HourlyRollup start(0,*,*,*,*,0) end(59,*,*,*,*,59)";
```

This is our hourly context...

This bean in query is not getting de-referenced and we are getting gbs of these objects.

```
  private static final String HOURLY_STATEMENT =
      "context HourlyRollup "
          + "select count(*) as xcount, hourlyFloor(min(from_time)), a, b, c, d, e, f,"
          + "g,h,sum(h),sum(i),j,k,l,"
          + "m,n,y,o,p,q,r "
          + "from io.common.Bean where Dir in (-5,-3,0,1) "
          + "group by a,b,c,d,e,f,g,Direction,h,"
          + "i,j,k,l,m,l,n,o,p output all "
          + "when terminated order by a,b,c,Dir,d,e";
  private static final int HOURLY = RollupPeriod.HOURLY.ordinal();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a select-clause selects properties of each event that are not in the group-by clause, that means that Esper cannot forget the event itself and keeps the events around until it is time to output and terminate.
This type of query is http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.2.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#processingmodel_aggregation_batch_group_agg

When a select-clause only has aggregated properties plus un-aggregated properties that appear in the group-by clause that mean Esper can forget the event and keep the aggregated value instead.
This type of query is http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.2.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#processingmodel_aggregation_batch_full_agg

So...check the expressions in the select-clause and make sure that event properties are either in the group-by clause, or are all aggregated for example "last(r)" or "first(r)" or similar.

Comment: Thanks...i introduced output rate limitter

Comment: After introduction of output rate limiter...i am still running to oom if input data is un-aggregated.I want to flush data if it crosses any size.